# Im trying to get an if statement to reply to a random number in python and display and print a message

Tags: python, if-statement, random

I'm trying to get an if statement to recognize a randomly generated number but I don't know what is going wrong, it just ends the program as soon as i hit start and does not print anything, so far I have this.

```
import random

random.randint(1,3)

if random.randint == ('1'):
    print('message')
```

I have tried changing the random.randint(1,3) into a variable by making it "a == ('random.randint(1,3)" but that did not work either. Does anyone know whats going wrong with it?

P.S: Sorry if the question is asked badly, I don't use this site much.

Comment: `==` checks two number (or anything equally).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on multiple fundamental conceptual errors and is unlikely to be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problem with your code.

`randint()` creates a number like `1`. It will never make a string like `'1'`. Additionally `random.randint` is a function. `random.randint == ('1')` will never be true, because a function is never never be equal to a number or a string. You want to compare the result of *calling* the function to an integer.

```
import random

num = random.randint(1,3)

if num == 1:
    print('message')
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint()` is a function - therefore, you have to save its output in a variable, or else the value will be lost. For instance:

```
import random

rand_num = random.randint(1,3)

if rand_num == 1:
    print('message')
```